# toggleClass on separate child elements

Tags: jquery, click, toggleclass

Im using the toggleClass method in a function like this:

**JS**

```
$('section .handle').click(function() {
    $('section h3 i').toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="handle clearfix">
                <h3>item one <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></h3>
            </div>
            <ul class="panel">
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="handle clearfix">
                <h3>item two <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></h3>
            </div>
            <ul class="panel">
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

now the problem is that i have several "i" elements and i need the class to be toggled on each single element, while like this the class is toggled on all of them.

Comment: Please provide your HTML structure..

Comment: added some html, it's just a part but it repeat itself several times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` to reference to the clicked element and then simply find the `<i>` inside it.

```
$('section .handle').click(function() {
    $("i", this).toggleClass('rotate');
});
```